# How to extract substring from a string using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to extract the user name and the date from the following string:

```
Syed Arafath on Jan 7, 2015
Capt.KSD on Dec 30, 2014
chakradharalasakani on Dec 29, 2014
mitesh0123 on Dec 18, 2014
Aparajita61@yahoo.in on Dec 3, 2014
123chetan on Oct 28, 2014
```

I want the output as follows:

```
Syed Arafath
Capt.KSD
chakradharalasakani
mitesh0123
Aparjita61@yahoo.co.in
Jan 7,2015
Dec 30, 2014
Dec 29,2014
Dec 18,2014
Dec 3, 2014
Oct 28, 2014
```

In all I want to split the string "Syed Arafath on Jan 7, 2015" into 2 strings, one containing the username and the other containing the date.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*) on (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matches(input);
if( m.matches() ) {
    String username = m.group(1);
    String date = m.group(2);
} else {
    throw new Exception("Did not match expected pattern");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do a split on `\\s+on\\s+` and you should get what you want

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/29

EDIT:

use `\\s+on\\s+(?!.*\bon\b)`

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/30

If you care about `Syed on Arafath` too.The lookahead makes sure split occurs on the last `on` .

Comment: What if `Syed Arafath`'s name was instead `Syed on Arafath`?

Comment: you need to use `\\s+`

Comment: carefull with the `on` inside the lookahead..

Answer (score 1):

Just split your input according to the below regex,

```
"\\s+on\\s+(?=\\S+\\s+\\d{1,2},)"
```

Code:

```
String txt = "Syed on Arafath on Jan 7, 2015";
String[] parts = txt.split("\\s+on\\s+(?=\\S+\\s+\\d{1,2},)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[Syed on Arafath, Jan 7, 2015]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a direct regex is preferrable to splitting:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.*) on .*").matcher(input);
m.matches();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

The *greedy* quality of the `*` quantifier guarantees that any occurrence of `on` within the name will be grabbed by it and only the *last* occurence of `on` will be matched by the `on` literal.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to split you can use replaceAll

```
    String name = s.replaceAll("(.*) on .*", "$1");
    String date = s.replaceAll(".*(\\w{3} \\d{1,2}, \\d{4}).*", "$1");
```